# How to find missing date from a column in SQL table?

Tags: sql-server

I've a table with the following structure:

```
TABLE [dbo].[UploadedFiles](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FileName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[FilePath] [varchar](200) NULL,
[UploadedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
```

[screen shot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhlRZ.jpg)

I need to find and show those date which is missing based on the [DateCreated] column. For example if there is no data for the 3rd of this month into the column [DateCreated] on the Database then I've to find it and show. But unfortunately I'm unable to find a way to do this. I would appreciate most if anyone in here can help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use this: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/  to paste your data and turn it into a text table.

Comment: that all between max and min date in database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Tally/Calendar table is the way to go.

However, you can do this via an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Select MissingDate = D
 From (Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,(Select min(DateCreated) from UploadedFiles),(Select max(DateCreated) from UploadedFiles))+1) 
              D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),cast((Select min(DateCreated) from UploadedFiles) as date)) 
        From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2) A
 Left Join UploadedFiles B on D=cast(DateCreated as date)
 Where DateCreated is null
```

**Returns**

```
MissingDate
2017-06-03
```

**Sample Data**

```
DateCreated
2017-06-01 11:47:00.000
2017-06-02 11:41:00.000
2017-06-04 11:55:00.000
2017-06-05 11:79:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution

Comment: @user7336033 Happy it helped